Nusselt number for developing turbulent flow
I need to develop a uniform method to cool a plate 1 degree, our idea was to let helium flow under it to transfer heat via convection. I concluded by some calculations that the Nusselt number for laminar flows would be approximately one, so only convection dominant for turbulent flow. I then need to determine the convective heat transfer coefficient $h$. I approximate by using formula's for the Nusselt number. For fully developed turbulent flow this would be
$Nu = 0.023Re^{0.8}Pr^{0.3}$
But now I found out that for our measurements the entrance length is too long, and the flow is not fully developed yet. How or where could I find such an equation?

You are dealing with flow over a flat plate, so the formula you presented is not appropriate; it applies only to turbulent flow in a tube.  For non-fully-developed flow, you have a boundary layer growing along the plate, and the Nusselt Number depends on position along the plate.  See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena for heat transfer in flow over a flat plate.

It is a tube though, there are walls at the end and under because it has to be realizable, so it can't be infinitely big.

Well you didn't provide a diagram of your system, so how were we supposed to know that.
